# Android 4.2 GPS icon cant be removed from notification bar

Tags: android, gps, location, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have a problem with the localization only in Android 4.2.2 devices.

When i use the normal process to get a localization and the fine-location permission is enabled the GPS icon never disapear. 
The problem is that the icon appear even the localization is not fetched by the GPS, for example with the getLastKnownLocation (for example with this usefull tip https://code.google.com/p/android-protips-location/source/browse/trunk/src/com/radioactiveyak/location_best_practices/utils/GingerbreadLastLocationFinder.java ) or with the network provider.

The localization process is normal, based on the location best pratices: https://code.google.com/p/android-protips-location/source/browse/trunk/src/com/radioactiveyak/location_best_practices/ project
creates by Reto Meier in this post:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html

Of course, the locationmanager and listener are stoped and put it to null. 
The problem is only for the Android 4.2.2 version. 
do you know if this is a Android bug?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: have you chcjed if the icon disapoears after some time (minutes)

Comment: Only when closes the app. Anyway is not aceptable for my app that the icon appear :S

Comment: Are you actually testing on hardware? Emulators rarely remove the GPS icon, in my experience.

Comment: Yes, in a Nexus 7, Nexus 4 (with android aosp and other with Cyanogen) and a Galaxy Nexus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this describes your problem:

[Google Bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39745)

It looks like a bug to me